# Get all the number between two numbers random

Tags: c#, random, shuffle

I'm not sure, if this question is unique, but I couldn't find the answer.

I want a good way to get numbers between 1 to 9 (including 9) randomly in C#, and I want to have all the 9 numbers. So I need a function that returns 9 numbers between 1 to 9 and I need every number exactly once.

for example, the result would look like this:
4,3,2,6,9,7,1,5,8

Comment: google `fisher yates shuffle`

Comment: implementation in `C#` @ http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle

Comment: I assume you didn't find a duplicate because you weren't aware that what you want is called a "shuffle". If you look for questions with that tag, you'll find lots :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just do this:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var numbers =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, 9)
        .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
        .ToArray();
```

An example result I got was:

[image: example result]

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go:

```
public void Shuffle(List<int> list)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int k = random.Next(i + 1);
        int val = list[k];
        list[k] = list[i];
        list[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
Shuffle(list);
```